# Please add a full-frame text editor to StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor, code

edit #2: here's what the editor looks like in SBS mode when using SOX

[image]

Done and done. Thanks @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ

edit: My point here is that when editing code there is a lot of unused screen real-estate. I don't understand why people wouldn't want to improve the editing experience on SO. It can be better and it should be better. It's frustrating that people don't want to improve it.

Editing large code blocks on SO is not good, 40% of that screen real-estate is just the similar questions block:

[image: SO]

vs. reddit's full page editor:

[image: Reddit]

So the question is: can we make editing code on SO as easy as it is on Reddit? Has this been discussed? Why don't we have nice things too?

Comment: Really dislike that horizontal scroll bar in the code section I can see on Reddit. Ugh.

Comment: Yeah me too. Wonder why it's there at all, seems like they have something set wrong.

Answer (score 9):

It's unnecessary and rather contradictory to the fact that it's desirable to submit *short self contained compilable examples*. See www.sscce.org.

An editor that facilitates uploading large amounts of code will cause the upload of large amounts of code. We don't want that.

The markdown format works well enough. It's also nice to be able to see the question preview window too.

Comment: It's really easy for an SSCCE to have 100 lines of code. That means a lot of scrolling up and down to check your preview as your editing. It's much easier to deal with that on reddit.

Comment: I really agree with this. We don't need any more 3GB code dumps than we already have.

Comment: Well sure. But it can be really difficult to guess exactly how much code someone needs to see to solve your problem. So, me, I err on the side of more code than less. The question I just asked was 95 lines and it was a pain to edit on SO.

Comment: I still don't see how even 100 lines of code can be considered appropriate for a Q&A site. Note that none of the stack exchange sites are forums.

Comment: When you have code that is not working and you're really not sure why how do you decide exactly how much to include? Perhaps you've left out an important part and the question will be unanswerable without it. 100 lines seems completely reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

To make it a bit easier, you can install [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088), a userscript that I'm one of the developers of that adds a 'side by side' mode to the editor:

[image]

so you can use the entire length of your screen to edit the code and see the preview right next to it!

It won't make it full screen but does allow you to extend it as much as you want without moving the preview even lower down

Comment: YES! Thanks. And thanks for not saying "it's fine the way it is" because I feel that that's what I've gotten so far. I have 15k rep on SO, I don't really need the "How to Format" box taking up 40% of my screen real estate and white space taking up another 15%.

Answer (score 2):

The inline editor is unlocked at 2K. The full page one is still available at /posts/id/edit.

You can probably find a [userscript](//stackapps.com/questions/tagged/editing) to have this linked by default ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41288080/edit -- that looks the same, not full page, still has a lot of unnecessary white space (you might not be able to get to that page)